# Exception on ConvertTimeToUtc

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Hello I have an exception when converting local time to UTC. I run my application
on Windows where "Russian Standard Time" is set.

```
public Convert()
{
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;

           // this converstion works
            TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dt, TimeZoneInfo.Local);

            // now let's get local timezone by id
            TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Russian Standard Time");

            if (TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id == tz.Id)
            {
                // this is just to make sure we have the same timezones
            }

// this conversion does not work
// throws exception System.ArgumentException
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dt1, tz);

}
```

UPDATE

Exception text is saying - cannot complete coversion because Kind property of datetime
is wrong. For example if Kind is Local the timezone must have value of TimeZoneInfo.Local.

Sorry this is not a copypaste - original message is not in english.

Comment: Can you add the full text of the ArgumentException to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TimeZoneInfo.Equals` method does not only compare on the Id: it also tests that the two timezones have the same adjustment rules (`TimeZoneInfo.HasSameRules`) - you can see this using Reflector.

I suspect that the Local timezone is in fact using daylight savings time, whereas `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Russian Standard Time")` is returning a timezone without daylight savings time.

You should be able to check this easily using the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495915.aspx) says:

> ArgumentException
>   dateTime.Kind is DateTimeKind.Utc and sourceTimeZone does not equal TimeZoneInfo.Utc.
>   -or-
>   dateTime.Kind is DateTimeKind.Local and sourceTimeZone does not equal TimeZoneInfo.Local.

and that seems to be the problem. `DateTime.Now` returns a *DateTimeKind.Local*.
But using [DateTime.SpecifyKind()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.specifykind.aspx) works for me:

```
dt1 = DateTime.SpecifyKind( dt, DateTimeKind.Unspecified );
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc( dt1, tz );
```

Comment: Yes it works for me too. When DateTime.Kind is set to Unspecified it is ok.

Comment: But i wonder why the exception is thrown? That could only mean
there is TimeZoneInfo reference check against TimeZoneInfo.Local

Comment: @Captain: yes, it seems that the method compares *TimeZoneInfo* and *DateTimeKind*